# Game Of Life loop error

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

So I'm currently working on a program based on Conway's Game of Life, and this certain method requires me to update the 2d array to define which cells are alive. I've run my JUnit tests, but when the test for the method runs, it says it's infinitely looping. Any ideas why?

```
public void update() {
    boolean temp ;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns(); j++) {
            temp = false;
            if (cellAt(i, j)) {
                temp = true;
            }
            if (temp=true) {
                if (neighborCount(i, j) < 2 || neighborCount(i, j) > 3) {
                    society[i][j] = false;
                }
            } else {
                if (neighborCount(i, j) == 3) {
                    society[i][j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the other methods that are used in this one

cellAt():

```
public boolean cellAt(int row, int col) {
    if (society[row][col] == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

neighborCount():

```
public int neighborCount(int row, int col) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = ((row + numberOfRows() - 1) % numberOfRows()); i == ((row + 1) % numberOfRows())
            || i == row
            || i == (((row + numberOfRows() - 1)) % numberOfRows())
            || i == numberOfRows(); i++) {
        i = i % numberOfRows();
        for (int j = (((col + numberOfColumns() - 1)) % numberOfColumns()); j == ((col + 1) % numberOfColumns())
                || j == col
                || j == (((col + numberOfColumns() - 1)) % numberOfColumns())
                || j == numberOfColumns(); j++) {
            j = j % numberOfColumns();
            if (society[i][j] == true) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: given that the advise on temp==true hasn't solved the problem you should look at the functions numberOfRows, numberOfColumns.. make sure in your setup they are assigned properly or neighborCount. Your code is likely not very efficient since you call neighbourCount(i,j) several times... Other than that difficult to help without more detail of your code.. Then we can talk about the correctness of the code... but this is another battle...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use comparison(`==`) instead of assignment(`=`) here:

```
        if (temp=true) {
```

which will always return `true`

Change it to

```
        if (temp == true) {
```

or simply use "Jean-François Savard" suggestion

```
if(temp)
```

Comment: Thanks! The test still will not run though

Comment: I think it would be better to simply use `if(temp)`

Comment: I had just if(temp) originally but i thought that might be causing the loop

Comment: @moo That was one of the problems. Try to use a debugger to see what is going against the expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. neighborCount() was just horribly written and the for loops were repeating.